# Меня сегодня исправили за неправильное написание

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я не очень сильно разбираюсь в русском языке, но мне кажется был прав. Подскажите, как правильно? Играть ЗА   Джилл(имя персонажа из игры) или играть НА Джилл? и почему этот вариант правильный

Comment: Меня сегодня поправили, а не исправили. Исправить (выпрямить) можно горбатую спину, ошибку итд. Правильно за джил, но "на джил" тоже вполне возможно, это сленг

Comment: @user190920 Играть на Бэтмене? Это же не режим.

Answer (score 0):

**За** Джилл играть можно только тогда, когда выходишь на бой с кем-то под флагом Джилл или в армии Джилл.
Играть **на** Джилл:

1. (карточный жаргон) в партии играть так, чтобы Джилл выиграла.
2. Джилл ездовое животное и Ваш персонаж на нем постоянно ездит.

Если Джилл это Ваш персонаж, то Вы играете им, **без предлогов**: играть Джиллой, если это имя склоняется, или играть персонажем/персом Джилл, если не склоняется.

Comment: за 14) а) *кого-что* Указывает на лицо, вместо или взамен которого кто-либо действует или от имени которого совершается действие.

Comment: Джилл не лицо, которое действует. Если она персонаж другого игрока, а я хам и хакер, то я могу играть Джилл за её хозяина, а не за нее. Если она НПС, то взломав игру я буду управлять ей (то есть играть ей) вместо программы игры, а не за Джилл.  Актеры в кукольном театре играют куклами, а не играют за них.  В играх играть персонажем  это значит управлять им, а управляя кем-то нельзя сказать, что управляю за него.

Comment: Но так очень часто говорят. А то, что очень часто используется, автоматически становится правильным.

Comment: Если Вы правы, тогда автора вопроса не поправили бы :-)

Comment: Может, человек просто не знаком с таким. Люди поправляют ещё в таком случае.

Answer (score 0):

Говорят и так и так, смотря какой контекст и какая игра:

Про мастерство игры на инструментах и прочем говорят "играть на" - пианино, гитаре, трубе, бильярде.

Но тут речь идет не только про скилл "игры", но и про ролевую часть, поэтому можно говорить и "за", то есть играешь за персонажа.

Либо вообще без предлога можно сказать, я играю вещью - я играю Джилл, как я играю куклой.

Для меня более предпочтительны 1 и 3 варианты, второй не нравится, так как связан с ролевыми манипуляциями, типа как "я решаю за неё", как будто Джилл нечто одушевленное и обладающее свободой воли. "За", говорят когда кто-то находится за чем-то, либо заменяет собой другого, живого, конечно, а не компьютерный анимированный алгоритм. То есть нельзя сказать: - где топор?/ - Я за него.

*Даже те офицеры, которые играли за перегородкой в карты, скоро бросили игру и перешли к самовару, подчиняясь общему настроению ухаживанья за Марьей Генриховной.* Толстой.

*— Возьми мои деньги и играй за меня, мне сегодня не везет. Тут есть еще рублей восемьсот.* Гейнце.

Comment: У вас тоже значок сам поменялся? Какой-то баг произошёл. Новый мне вообще не нравится.

Comment: @oleedd да, ну это же рандом, если хочешь, чтобы не менялся - ставь свою картинка;)

Comment: Это баг. Он не должен сам меняться. Он никогда раньше не менялся. А щас сначала поменялся на некоторых SE сайтах, а теперь и сюда перешёл(

Comment: этот значок не нравится - так установите аватару, которая нравится, не пойму я вас)

Comment: @user190920 Хочу старый, зелёный значок. А он пропал. Ёлки-палки, у вас тоже поменялся.

Comment: Так берите пример с Василия, вот уж кто не жалуется на значок

Answer (score 0):

Правильным предлогом является тот предлог, который фактически устоялся в речи. В данном случае фактически устоялся предлог ‟за”, играют за персонажа. Использование предлога ‟на” в данной ситуации является грамматической ошибкой. Я ни разу не слышал, чтобы люди говори, что в новом Street Fighter они будут играть НА Люке, а не за Люка. Никто не использует в такой ситуации предлог ‟на”, в том числе ни в каких сленгах такого нет.